# Is it correct to include individual files in the -classpath argument to the Java VM?

Tags: java, jvm, command-line-arguments

Current practice here is to include individual files (other than JAR files, such as configuration files or data files) in the classpath.  Is this considered correct and why or why not?

**Update:**

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html:

> -cp classpath
>       Specify a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Class path entries are separated by semicolons
>   (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the
>   CLASSPATH environment variable.

This question can also be interpreted as asking, does the above enumeration of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives contain an implicit "and nothing else"?

**Update:**

Un-accepting an answer because after I changed my classpath to include a directory rather than specific files, the program began working.  So I am investigating whether there was some other issue involved or whether specifying individual files doesn't work (or at least, doesn't always work).

**Update:**

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html:

> Classpath entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or .jar files) are ignored.

Comment: Perhaps a little bit on what issues you are facing ?

Answer (score 2):

The classpath contains either directories or jar files

Comment: But not other files?  Yes, no, and why or why not?

Comment: because the classes and resources are searched in directories or jar files (or zip files). So adding a plain file to the classpath is pointless.

Comment: @Jesper: Java seems to work fine when individual non-jar files are included.  So, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Doug adding for example individual `*.class` files does not work. Java will not be able to find the classes in those files if you try that.

Comment: @Jesper, what about configuration files?

Comment: @Doug according to a_horse_with_no_name (see his answer) that should work. If it works, I see no reason to suspect that it is "incorrect". Do whatever you think works for you...

Comment: @MauricePerry: it's not pointless to add "plain" files as a single element to the classpath. The DB2 JDBC driver requires exactly that in order to find its license file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how do they enforce that requirement?  (I will open a new question if it seems like a worthwhile independent thread.)

Comment: @DougTreadwell: I guess it's "enforced" by the fact that the driver will not work if the files cannot be loaded as a resource.

Answer (score 2):

If your program loads those other files using `Classloader.getResourceAsStream()` (or some similar way) then it makes perfect sense to include those files in the classpath.

This is common e.g. for license files that are bundled with an application.

So yes this is considered correct - at least from my point of view.

Comment: Can you respond to Maurice Perry's comment in his own answer to this question?  Isn't it pointless to add a plain file to the classpath rather than the directory it's in?  Or if we only need one file, does that save some time or prevent file name conflicts?

Comment: @DougTreadwell: no I don't think it's pointless. There are some JDBC drivers out there, that require exactly that setup in order for their license file to be loaded.

Comment: How do the drivers know whether their licenses were included exactly by an absolute path with their full file name or were discovered in some path?

Comment: @DougTreadwell: I assume they load them through `getResourceAsStream()` or `getSystemResourceAsStream()`

Comment: and those methods require a file to be given by absolute and full path in the classpath?

Comment: @DougTreadwell: once they are part of the classpath, I don't think it matters if they were specified with a relative or absolute path in the `-cp` argument.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html:

> -cp classpath
>
> Specify a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files.
>   Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the user class path consists
>   of the current directory (.).
>
> For more information on class paths, see Setting the Class Path
>   (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html).

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html:

> Classpath entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or
>   .jar files) are ignored.

Further:

> Each classpath should
>   end with a filename or directory depending on what you are setting the
>   class path to:
>
> - For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file.
> - For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the .class files.
> - For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the
>     full package name).